# Automatic height of the webview

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

I have a xamarin forms application and I have inserted a webview inside the layout stack, the problem is that I have multiple pages and in each page the length of the content is different from the others.
I wanted to ask if there was a way to have the webview automatically adjust the height.
I have read other similar questions on the site, but I admit they seemed confusing to me.
This is my code xaml

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="White">
        <WebView
                x:Name="wvSite" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                HeightRequest="2300" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reset the webview height according to the content height when loading page finished via custom renderer.

**Android:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App1.Droid
{
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    public CustomWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(e.NewElement));
    }
}
internal class CustomWebViewClient : Android.Webkit.WebViewClient
{
    private WebView webView;

    public CustomWebViewClient(WebView webView)
    {
        this.webView = webView;
    }
    public async override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
    {
        if (webView != null)
        {
            int i = 10;
            while (view.ContentHeight == 0 && i-- > 0) 
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100);
            webView.HeightRequest = view.ContentHeight;
             
        }
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}


}
```

**iOS:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), 
typeof(CustomWebviewRenderer))]
namespace App1.iOS
{
public class CustomWebviewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        NavigationDelegate = new CustomWebviewNavigationDelegate();
    }
}

internal class CustomWebviewNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    [Export("webview:didFinishNavigation:")]
    public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        //base.DidFinishNavigation(webView, navigation);
        webView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Width, webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is there also for ios?

Comment: I have updated my reply about how to do that on ios. You could check it.

Comment: Any update? Have you solved this issue?